# Why Netezza Sequence next value giving random values?

Tags: netezza

Sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE STG.TEMP_PPC_SEQ AS BIGINT
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    MAXVALUE 2147483647
    NO CYCLE;
```

Select Query:

```
SELECT TPLCST.code,NEXT VALUE FOR STAGING.STG.TEMP_PPC_SEQ
FROM TEMP_PRODUCT_LIFE_CYCLE_STATUS_TYPE TPLCST
```

Result:

```
CODE    NEXTVAL
30  8
80  10008
40  30008
50  40015
10  40016
20  20008
```

I am getting nextval random. How can I make them sequential?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are random because Netezza is massively parallel and each SPU gets its own block of sequence values.

Comment: This answers it perfectly. Sequences is not a way to get a sequential order. It's to get a unique identifier, and it should be completely without any importance what the value is, as long as it is unique.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Row_number() over(order by <>) to get sequence value

please read below

http://www.enzeecommunity.com/message/8914

http://www.enzeecommunity.com/message/3272

Answer (score 0):

Are you attempting to make an autoincrement column? Netezza doesn’t do that. Moreover if you use a sequence generator it will be unique but not contiguous – there will be holes in the sequence.